# Flink tumbling event time window not triggering

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a pipeline where I am taking sensor events from each player of a football match (x/y coordinates) and calculating the distance each player has run over the entire game.

I want to keep a running sum of the distance they have each run and emit the stats for all players, as a single event, every second.

I have successfully calculated the running distance of each player and that works fine. If I run the following it outputs results as expected:

```scala
    val playerRunningStats = playerAverages.keyBy(_.entity.map(_.name))
      .window(GlobalWindows.create())
      .trigger(ContinuousEventTimeTrigger.of[GlobalWindow](Time.seconds(1)))
      .aggregate(new RunningDistanceAggregator)
      .print
```

**Results (subset for some players in 1st second):**

```
4> PlayerDistanceEvent(player 1,6.0)
11> PlayerDistanceEvent(player 2,3.414213562373095)
1> PlayerDistanceEvent(player 3,4.414213562373095)
9> PlayerDistanceEvent(player 4,3.0)
5> PlayerDistanceEvent(player 5,3.0)
...
```

Now I want to aggregate these results into one single event and send them out to a kafka topic but his is where I am encountering my issue. When I try to create a new `windowAll` aggregation and print it, nothing gets printed:

```scala
    val playerRunningStats = playerAverages.keyBy(_.entity.map(_.name))
      .window(GlobalWindows.create())
      .trigger(ContinuousEventTimeTrigger.of[GlobalWindow](Time.seconds(1)))
      .aggregate(new RunningDistanceAggregator)
      // New code below to combine results into a single event
      .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1)))
      .aggregate(new RunningDistanceSnapshotAggregator)
      .print
```

I know that my `RunningDistanceSnapshotAggregator` code works because when I change the `windowAll` to a `TumblingProcessingTimeWindow` the code seems to work fine. But I don't want to use processing time windows, I want to use event time windows right?

Code with processing time window that seems to work:

```scala
    val playerRunningStats = playerAverages.keyBy(_.entity.map(_.name))
      .window(GlobalWindows.create())
      .trigger(ContinuousEventTimeTrigger.of[GlobalWindow](Time.seconds(1)))
      .aggregate(new RunningDistanceAggregator)
      // Change to processing time window and it works fine
      .windowAll(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1)))
      .aggregate(new RunningDistanceSnapshotAggregator)
      .print
```

**Results:**

```
1> PlayerDistanceSnapshot(List(PlayerDistanceEvent(player 1,3.414213562373095), PlayerDistanceEvent(player 2,4.0), PlayerDistanceEvent(player 3,3.0), PlayerDistanceEvent(player 4,2.0), PlayerDistanceEvent(player 5,6.0))
```

Why can't I use an event time window for the second `windowAll` and why doesn't it produce any results if I use an event time window?

Comment: How are you generating event timestamps and watermarks?

Comment: @bzu since the source is just a file at the moment I'm doing the following at the source: `val eventStream = env.addSource(new FootballFileSource(eventFileLocation)).setParallelism(1).assignAscendingTimestamps(x => x._1)`.

The first element of the tuple is the millisecond timestamp of the sensor event.

Comment: Do you also set `env.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(millis)`? I haven't used this timestamp assigner, but if it is periodic it will be difficult to test (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73097154/4648969).

Comment: In any case, I would first double-check that the watermarks are coming through and have values which you expect.

Comment: Hmm I did try that but still seeing the same issue. What's the best way to check the value of the watermarks?

Comment: Inside any process function you should get context as input param and use it to access watermarks. Maybe `ctx.timerService().currentWatermark()` (sorry, might be wrong, but cannot check it right now).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, when I add the process function to the pipeline (right before the windowall) and print the watermarks they increment as expected. But as soon as I add the windowAll and use a processallwindowfunction it doesn't print anything.